# Android - Problems cropping a Bitmap to display in an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Thanks for reading, have been trying to get this going for days and have searched as much code as I can. As you will see below I have tried a number of approaches.

I am using a 3rd party device that returns a Bitmap of size 152 x 500. There is a black strip vertically down the left side that is 24 wide. So in actual fact what I am needing is a 128 x 500 which would start 24 in from the left.

Whatever I try I just cannot seem to get rid of that black strip when the image is saved.

Here is the code, sorry it's so much but I thought I would just show it all. Look for

// Scan Button Clicked
and
  Log.e("tag", "Wait For Scan Capture");

Much appreciate any help on this.

```
    public class ImageCaptureActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout ll_root;
    private Button btn_scan;
    private Button btn_process;

    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private Button mButton;
    private FingerView mImageView;
    private FPCDevKitInterface mFPCDevKit;


    public View minutiaView;
    public Bitmap tempBitmap;
    public Bitmap scanBitmap;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_login_scan);


        Log.e("tag", "0");
        //ll_root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_root);
        btn_scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);
        btn_process = (Button)findViewById(R.id.proceed_button);
        Log.e("tag", "1");

//      mFPCDevKit = new SSDDevice  ((UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));
//      mImageView = new FingerView(this, mFPCDevKit.createCompatibleBitmap());
//      mImageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200));

        //add view here.
        // ll_root.addView(mImageView);
        // Just keep it commented, because we cannot find the id of ll_root. it is currently null.
        Log.i("tag", "2");


        Log.e("tag", "5");

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/        
/* Following is the initial Screen Layout Section done as a Setup of the screen and Before the Capture is clicked */        

// Manually set up the screen layout 
        mLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

// Manually create the Button       
        mButton = new Button(this);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mButton.setText("Capture Image");


// Setup the FPC Service to get the finger scan from the device
        Log.e("tag", "Setup FPC");
        mFPCDevKit = new SSDDevice  ((UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));

// Call the FingerView function and then load the bitmap into mImageView
        Log.e("tag", "Load into mImageView");
        mImageView = new FingerView(this, mFPCDevKit.createCompatibleBitmap());

// Modify the viewing area for the scanned image size       
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(24+128,500));  // Left area plus image width and crop of right area

// Add the Button and the mImageView to the Layout
        Log.e("tag", "Add Views");
        mLayout.addView(mButton);
        mLayout.addView(mImageView);

// Display the screen
        Log.e("tag", "Display Screen");
        setContentView(mLayout); 

        // setContentView(R.layout.my_login_scan);

/* ----------- End Screen Layout Setup ------------------ */        

    }

    public static AlertDialog createCapturePromtDialog(Context context,
            DevKitType type) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        if (type == DevKitType.ASD)
            builder.setTitle("Place finger on sensor");
        else
            builder.setTitle("Swipe finger over sensor");

        return builder.create();
    }

    private class FingerView extends View {

        public Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Matrix mMatrix;

        public FingerView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
            super(context);
            mBitmap = bitmap;
            mMatrix = new Matrix();
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  // is the full screen area background colour as well as the template area colour
            setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Log.e("tag", "FingerView");
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return mBitmap;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            Log.e("onSizeChanged", "w = " + w + " h = " + h + " oldw = " + oldw
                    + " oldh = " + oldh);



            // This use to Scale the current bitmap fill the screen.
            // The last variable: Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL for fill two dimensions
            // Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER scale to center and keep the
            // width/height ratio.

            //mMatrix.setRectToRect(
            //      new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight()),
            //      new RectF(0, 0, w, h), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);          



            // Lets try to resize to 150 x 500 - Harry July 14 2013
//          mMatrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, 128, 500),new RectF(-24, 0, 150, 500), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

            Log.e("tag", "Inside onsizechanged " + 0);

/*  Scales image to fit into a new rectangle imageView
            Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
            RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
            RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
            m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
*/          



        }



        @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            Log.e("onDraw Begin","");
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, null);
            super.onDraw(canvas);

        }
    }



// Scan Button Clicked  
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.e("tag", "onClick happened");

        // Erase the scan area to White
        mImageView.getBitmap().eraseColor(Color.WHITE);   // Doesn't seem to make a difference

//          Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(128+24+24,500,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);     
        Log.e("onClick Enter second one= " + 0,
                "w = " + 0 + " h =" + 0);

        try {

            // Wait for the scanner and then load the image into mImageView.mBitmap
            mFPCDevKit.clearAbort();
            Log.e("tag", "Wait For Scan Capture");

            scanBitmap = mFPCDevKit.createCompatibleBitmap();
            mFPCDevKit.waitAndCaptureImage(mImageView.getBitmap());  //  Image displays in mImageView
            //mFPCDevKit.waitAndCaptureImage(scanBitmap);            // Tried to put image into a Bitmap



            //Create a new image bitmap and attach a brand new canvas to it
//          Bitmap minBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(scanBitmap);

            //Draw the image bitmap into the canvas
//          tempCanvas.drawBitmap(scanBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            //Draw everything else you want into the canvas, in this example a rectangle with rounded edges
//          tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1,y1,x2,y2), 2, 2, scanBitmap);

            //Attach the canvas to the ImageView
//          mImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), scanBitmap));



        //  @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA); canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint); if(item_id==3){ canvas.drawText(AppModel.contents, 100, 100, mPaint); } else{ canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); } } 

//          Bitmap mmBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageView.mBitmap, 22, 0, mImageView.mBitmap.getWidth()-100, mImageView.mBitmap.getHeight());
//          Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(mmBitmap);
//          mImageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);




            // Crop the image here.
            Log.e("before crop", "w = " + mImageView.getBitmap().getWidth()
                    + " h = " + mImageView.getBitmap().getHeight());

            // parameters show  w = 176 h = 500

        // Harry's mods to flow here --------


         // Bitmap HarryBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageView.getWidth(),mImageView.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //  Bitmap HarryBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(128,500,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(HarryBitmap);
//          mImageView.draw(canvas);

//          Bitmap resizedbitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap,24,0,150,500);
//          Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(resizedbitmap1);
//              mImageView.draw(canvas1);       


/* Try number 2 to approach              
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

            int targetWidth  = 128;
            int targetHeight = 500;

            Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scanBitmap);

            canvas.drawBitmap( scanBitmap, new Rect(24, 0, 176, 500),
                            new RectF(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), paint);

//            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
//            matrix.postScale(1f, 1f);
//            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetBitmap, 0, 0, 128, 500, matrix, true);
// 
//            //convert Bitmap to resource  
//            //BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
// 
//            canvas.drawBitmap( resizedBitmap, new Rect(24, 0, 128, 500),
//                    new Rect(0, 0, 128, 500), paint);

            mImageView.draw(canvas);
*/             



            Log.e("after crop", "w = " + mImageView.getBitmap().getWidth()
                    + " h = " + mImageView.getBitmap().getHeight());

            // end Harry's mods to flow --------



            // Save the image to the SD card for testing viewing
             saveScreen(mImageView.getBitmap());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mImageView.postInvalidate();
    }



// Not currently used - Harry July 14 2013
    private Bitmap cropBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 1, 1, 128, 500);
        Log.e("croped",
                "w = " + result.getWidth() + " h = " + result.getHeight());
        return result;
    }

    public void saveScreen(Bitmap bitmap) {

        Log.e("saveScreen Enter= " + bitmap.getByteCount(),
                "w = " + bitmap.getWidth() + " h =" + bitmap.getHeight());

        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String fname = "FPCKit.jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        /*
         * boolean done = false; int n = 1; do { String fname = "Image-" + n +
         * ".jpg"; file = new File(myDir, fname); if (!file.exists()) { done =
         * true; } n++; } while (!done);
         */
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            // bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            // Bitmap bmp = mImageView.getBitmap();
            // bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            Log.e("onSave bytes= " + bitmap.getByteCount(),
                    "w = " + bitmap.getWidth() + " h =" + bitmap.getHeight());
            //This will be as previous version. save entire image. 
            mImageView.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
//          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);



            out.flush();
            out.close();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this,
                    "Image saved to " + file.getAbsolutePath(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this,
                    "Exception saving image: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Try with this one: https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidImageCrop/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not really what I was looking for, I can't see that will address my problem. cheers